# How to rename file with multiple array using PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, multidimensional-array, rename

Hello I need rename a file with multiple array.
I have many file in the original folder with this format.
This is the example file.

```
20200909071608_11WWR3DT601_AE.job
20200909071608_11WWR3DT601_S1.job
```

I need to copy some file in that folder consider to file name that I initialize below.

1. I have xml file with this format
2. I need to mapping the crm and the priority value of each crm.
3. After mapping, then I need to rename the files that I copy with some information from the xml file.
4. I tried this, it works to copy the file, then rename it, but the file that rename is duplicated.

Anyone can help me please. Thank you.

```
$PathOperationalJob = "D:\Process"
$PathOriginalJob = "D:\Initial"

$SWPOfile = @("11WWR3DT601_AE", "11WWR3DT601_S1")
$CRM = @("AE", "S1")
$SSID = "8537"
$JobSequenceAgent = "D:\Service\Sequence.XML"
[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $JobSequence = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$JobSequenceFilePath = Resolve-Path ($JobSequenceAgent) -ErrorAction Stop
$JobSequence.Load($JobSequenceFilePath)
$Date = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
# Mapping SSID
foreach ($c in $CRM)
{

     $QuerySSID =  $JobSequence.assign.define.systemid | Where-Object {$_.value -like "*$SSID*"} |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty description | Where-Object {$_.crm -like "*$c*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty priority
     Write-Host "priority: $c $QuerySSID"

     Copy-Item -Path $PathOriginalJob\*$SWPOfile*.job $PathOperationalJob\11WWR3DT601 -ErrorAction Stop
     $SWPOfile | ForEach-Object {
          Copy-Item -Path $PathOriginalJob\*$_*.job $PathOperationalJob\18WWR3DT601 -ErrorAction Stop
          $GetAddJob = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathOperationalJob\11WWR3DT601\*$_*.job | 
          Rename-Item -NewName {"$QuerySSID`_$Date`_" + $_.Name.Replace('.job','.que')}
     }
    
}
```

Comment: `Copy-Item` can rename too. You don't realy need to call `Rename-Item`. `Copy-Item C:\test\source.txt c:\test\dest.txt`

Comment: but I need to do it in array @T-Me

Comment: What part of it is an array? or do you mean the `ForEach-Object `? You could create the destination string with `$_` too:  `Copy-Item C:\test\source.txt c:\test\dest-$_.txt`

Comment: these are in array $SWPOfile $CRM  $QuerySSID @T-Me

Comment: Does the line `Copy-Item -Path $PathOriginalJob\*$SWPOfile*.job ...` even work if `$SWPOfile` is an array?

Answer (score 0):

T-Me is correct, you can't put an array in wildcards like that. It won't unroll the array and copy files with those strings in the filenames. You should put it in the ForEach loop instead like this:

```
$SWPOfile | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = "$QuerySSID`_$Date`_" + $_.Name.Replace('.job','.que')
    Copy-Item -Path $PathOriginalJob\*$_*.job $PathOperationalJob\11WWR3DT601\$newName -ErrorAction Stop

    Copy-Item -Path $PathOriginalJob\*$_*.job -Destination $PathOperationalJob\18WWR3DT601 -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

This also lets you avoid having to use the `Rename-Item` command that was duplicating your files.